# Installing Vim: What is the difference betwen "--with-local-dir" and "includedir"

Tags: vim, ncurses, configure

My main goal is that I want to understand how parameters works in `./configure`. So, I decided to install **ncurses** and **vim** in `$HOME/local/`, so, as to not affect my system.

while configuring vim, I looked into `--with-local-dir` and `includedir`. I want to know what is the difference between them.

When I looked into [vim-git-INSTALL-script](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/INSTALL), it said:

```
Unix: LOCAL HEADERS AND LIBRARIES NOT IN /usr/local

Sometimes it is necessary to search different path than /usr/local for locally
installed headers (/usr/local/include) and libraries (/usr/local/lib).
To search /stranger/include and /stranger/lib for locally installed
headers and libraries, use:
    ./configure --with-local-dir=/stranger
```

I thought that was the purpose of `includedir`. I would appreciate if someone can tell me where I went wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conventionally (and per [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html)), **`includedir`** is used for the directory where the current program would *install* header files.  That's not the same as the places where the configure script might have to tell the compiler to find the header files needed to *compile* the program.

Comment: Thank you! That link is exactly what I was looking for.